# Trying to write a function to write less code

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I have a lot of "on change" handlers to store values in localStorage. Now I'm trying to shorten my code. This is one;

```
    $('input[name^="tornfalksgrand2"]').on('change', function () {

      let allItems = $('input[name^="tornfalksgrand2"]:checked').map(function(){
        return this.value;
      }).get();
      localStorage['tornfalksgrand2'] = JSON.stringify(allItems)

    });
```

So far I tried this function;

```
    function addDataToLocalStorage($input, $inputChecked, localStorageName ) {
      $input.on('change', function () {
        let allItems = $inputChecked.map(function(){
          return this.value;
        }).get();
        localStorage[localStorageName] = JSON.stringify(allItems)
      });
   }
```

And then run the function with this;

```
addDataToLocalStorage($('input[name^="tornfalksgrand2"]'), $('input[name^="tornfalksgrand2"]:checked'), 'tornfalksgrand2');
```

This stores an empty array in localStorage and not the value I want.
Any idea anyone?

Comment: Your first version is getting all checked items when the `change` event happens. Your second version is getting all checked items when your page loads, when you're setting up the event handler. The quick fix is simple: pass just the selector strings instead, and use `$(param)` inside your function so the selection happens at the time of the event. However this can be optimized further easily.

Comment: It seems to be that you are doing this backwards. Instead of calling `addDataToLocalStorage()`, which then sets up your `change` handler, I think you want to set up your `change` handler and within it, call `addDataToLocalStorage()`.

Comment: Here's a shorter way: https://jsfiddle.net/of0beytq/ (note that I named the function according to what it actually does)

Comment: @Chris G, your jsfiddle worked perfectly, thank you!